# How to delete a row in a data frame by name in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to delete a row from a data frame in which each row has a name. I cannot use indexes to delete the rows, only it's name. I have this dataframe:

```
DF<- data.frame('2014' = c(30,20,4, 50), '2015' = c(25,40,6, 65), row.names = c("mobile login", "computer login","errors", "total login"))
```

I've tried

```
DF["mobile login",] <- NULL
```

and

```
DF <- DF[-"mobile login",]
```

and more combinations with no results.

What can I do? Thanks

PS: The last row is the sum of the first two (there are other in the real DF, that's only an example), and once they are added, I don't need them, only the result, the "total login" value.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use `%in%` along with an appropriate subset of your data frame.  To remove the rows named `errors` and `mobile login` you can use the following code:

```
row.names.remove <- c("errors", "mobile login")

> DF[!(row.names(DF) %in% row.names.remove), ]
               X2014 X2015
computer login    20    40
total login       50    65
```

Comment: Ahh. What I like most in R: the easy and intuitive syntax! Especially for tasks as complex as deleting a row. Thank you for providing this, it cut down my trial and error time by hours.

Comment: This method turns my DF into a num and loses the row names